# difference between padding and android:gravity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I am trying to design a screen and unable to appreciate the difference between android:layout_gravity and android:padding, if both align the view based on parent layout, then how different are they from each other. Please advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[Padding](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) (see the "Size, Padding and Margins" heading in that link) creates an absolute distance (usually in pixels) between the edge of a view and it's content.

[Gravity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android%3alayout_gravity) positions an item relative to it's parent: in the center, to the left, to the right, top, bottom, etc. but you cannot supply an absolute distance from an edge, e.g. 10 pixels, without using margin (or padding; read the Android docs for information on the difference between those two).

Answer (score 1):

I like to think of padding as a box inside the layout where your contents will be placed (alignment baed on the gravity). Where as, without any padding, gravity will change the alignment of the contents with respect to the layout border.

Comment: thnks azharb but my original question is now "difference between padding and android:gravity"

Answer (score 0):

android:padding is setting the absolute padding values within the current layout. android:layout_gravity set the gravity of the current layout with respect to the parent.

```
<Linearlayout android:id="@+id/L1">
 <Linearlayout android:id="@+id/L2"
     ...
     android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
     android:padding="5px">
     <TextView android:id="@+id/T1"
         .../>

</Linearlayout>
```

Hence L2 is aligned to the left bottom corner of L1 and android:padding sets a padding of 5px on each of the four sides for the layout L2 (which affects the childlayouts of L2 = T1).